# X-Axis Labels from CSV?

Tags: python, graph

I'm trying to make the labels of my graph correlate to the months column of a CSV file I've made, however when the program is run the graph prints perfectly but the months do not show on the x axis, just numbers. How do I fix this?
EDIT: The error it gives me is "ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units"
My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

crimedata = pd.read_csv('MasterFileCSV.csv')

homicide = crimedata['Homicide Convictions'].values
robbery = crimedata['Robbery Convictions'].values
crimDamage = crimedata['Criminal Damage Convictions'].values
month = crimedata['month'].values

fig = plt.figure()
plt.xticks(month, rotation='vertical')
plt.plot(np.arange(len(homicide)), homicide, color='red', label='Homicide Convictions')
plt.plot(np.arange(len(robbery)), robbery, color='green', label='Robbery Convictions')
plt.plot(np.arange(len(crimDamage)), crimDamage, color='blue', label='Criminal Damage Convictions')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Comment: What is  `crimedata['month'].values`?

Comment: It's supposed to take data from the months column of my CSV file. 18 months formatted as May-14 to Oct-15